# iOS 8 : How to check the given email address is really existing or not in iphone sdk?

Tags: ios

How to check the given validated email address is existing in live in iPhone sdk. Give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, unless you hit the mail server associated with the email provided

Comment: Usually people send E-mail verification for this purposes.

Comment: its not the business of ios sdk . Its the mail server which confirms mail validity

Comment: can u check my answer

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

check this link dude

http://iwantmyreal.name/blog/2013/07/28/email-address-validation-in-ios/

And try to follow below instructions

**CocoaPod**

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'GuardPost-ObjectiveC', '~> 0.1.1'
```

**Installation**

```
$ pod install
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import <GPGuardPost.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Register the mailgun API Key
    [GPGuardPost setPublicAPIKey:@"pubkey-from-mailgun"];

    // Other app launch options here...

    return YES;
}
@end
```

**Email Address Validation**

```
[GPGuardPost validateAddress:self.emailField.text
                     success:^(BOOL validity, NSString *suggestion) {
                        NSLog(@"API call successful");
                     }
                     failure:^(NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"There was an error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address, although others suggested, I would send a verification email, it's a common practice.

Email addresses are often requested as input to website as user identification for the purpose of data validation. While there are companies that provide services to validate an email address at the time of entry, normally using an Application programming interface, there is no guarantee that it will provide accurate results.[16]

An email address is generally recognized as having two parts joined with an at-sign (@). However, the technical specification detailed in RFC 822 and subsequent RFCs are more extensive, offering complex and strict restrictions.[17]

It is impossible to match these restrictions with a single technique. Using regular expressions results in long patterns giving incomplete results.[18]

Syntactically correct, verified email addresses do not guarantee email box existence. Thus many mail servers use other techniques and check the mailbox existence against relevant systems such as the Domain Name System for the domain part or using callback verification to check if the mailbox exists. This is however often disabled to avoid directory harvest attack.

Assuring an email address is of a good quality, requires a combination of various validation techniques. Large websites, bulk mailers or spammers, require fast algorithms that predict validity of email address. Such methods depend heavily on heuristic algorithms and statistical models.[19]

Unfortunately, many websites evaluate the validity of email addresses incorrectly, rejecting addresses containing valid characters, such as + or / signs, or setting arbitrary length limitations (e.g., 30 characters). RFC 3696 provides specific advice for validating Internet identifiers, including email addresses.

The new HTML5 forms implemented in many browser, using the new email state of the input element, allow email address validation to be handled by the browser.[20]

Email address internationalization provides for a much larger range of characters than many current validation algorithms allow, such as all Unicode characters above U+0080, encoded as UTF-8.